# plotting the means with confidence intervals with ggplot

Tags: r

I have some data that I have gathered from a model. I want to plot the size of a population over time. I have the population size at each time step, and 100 replicates. I would like to plot the mean population size for each time step, and also the 95% confidence intervals (as a shading if possible).

I haven't used `ggplot` before. I have just been using the ordinary (base) plots in R so far. But I want to see what the `ggplot` would look like.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplot(data=model1, aes(x=steps., y= pop-size, col='blue')) + 
   geom_line()
```

This plots all the points, and it looks good, but I don't know how to just plot the means and add the confidence intervals.

Comment: You should check here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Have a look at `?stat_smooth` as well.

Comment: Since you're (relatively) new to SO, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) on how to pose a well-crafted question that is more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you have replicated data, and you want to plot mean/CL, you are probably better off using `stat_summary(...)` which is designed for (you guessed it) summarizing data. Basically, it applies a function to all the y-values for each x-value (so, the `mean(...)` function for example), and then plots the result using whatever geometry you specify. Here's an example:

```
# sample data - should be provided in question
set.seed(1)      # for reproducible example
time <- 1:25
df   <- data.frame(time,
                   pop=rnorm(100*length(time), mean=10*time/(25+time)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pop))+ 
  stat_summary(geom="ribbon", fun.data=mean_cl_normal, width=0.1, conf.int=0.95, fill="lightblue")+
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, linetype="dashed")+
  stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y=mean, color="red")
```

[image]

So here we have 3 layers: a layer that summarizes the y-values using the `mean(...)` function, and plots using `geom="line"`, a layer that summarizes the same way but plots using `geom="point"`, and a layer that uses `geom="ribbon"` This geom requires `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics, so we use the built-in ggplot function `mean_cl_normal` to generate those based on the assumption that the error is normally distributed and that, therefore, the means follow a t-distribution. Type `?hmisc` for documentation on the various functions that are useful for confidence limits. The layers render in the order of the code, so, since you want shading, we need to put the error ribbon first.

Finally, it is of course possible to summarize the data yourself, using `dplyr` or some such, but I don't really see the point of doing that.

**Update** (based on recent comment):
Looks like the most recent version of `ggplot2` (2.0.0) has a different way of specifying the arguments to `fun.data`. This works in the new version:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=pop))+ 
    stat_summary(geom="ribbon", fun.data=mean_cl_normal, 
                 fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), fill="lightblue")+
    stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y=mean, linetype="dashed")+
    stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y=mean, color="red")
```

The problem with the `width=...` argument is a bit more subtle I think: it actually isn't needed (in the original answer I used error bars, and forgot to remove this argument when I changed it to ribbon). The older version of ggplot2 ignored extraneous arguments (hence, no error). The new version, evidently, is more strict. Probably this is better.

Comment: I slightly prefer `stat_summary(geom="ribbon", fun.data=mean_cl_normal, colour=NA,alpha=0.1)`

Comment: I prefer the error bars actually, but in fact I misread the question - OP wants ribbons. I edited my response.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I'll make sure I put sample data etc. in my question next time.

Comment: This is great, but did the new ggplot2 break it?  When I run the above code with ggplot2_2.2.0 and Hmisc_3.17-1, I get this error: Error: Unknown parameters: width, conf.int

Comment: Thanks, that's great!